# Salesforce / Sites / Automation, where is it?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I'm working inside a Salesforce instance and I have a domain + site setup with registration and login (within the same Salesforce instance).

After someone registers an account on the Salesforce site, there's an instance of a custom object created (let's call it `Contact`).

There was an automation working at the same time the Contact was created that sent the information to a Wordpress instance. For some reason, that stopped working.

Where, within Salesforce, can I find this sort of automation?

It's either an automation after someone submits the register form in the Salesforce site or after a custom object gets created.

Answer (score -1):

"Active" search

Setup -> Debug logs -> set a new debug log on the special "{your site name} Guest User" and try to register that contact. With any luck it should capture something (it might be after few seconds delay because my guess is this would be a `@future`, `Queueable` or similar kind of code). It's possible your log will even contain the error message (if any) which - because this "future" is detached from main transaction - nobody sees in the UI.

"Passive" search

Do "Remote Site Settings", "Named Credentials" mean anything to you? Are you able to run a search for the named credential's name or even the target website in the code (or anything really even `new Http()` would be a good start)? Do you know whether it was coded or configured ("external functions" it's called I think, calling REST APIs from flows). if it's really old could even be "time based workflow" and "outbound messages"